# My script shows outputs of multiple Get-LocalGroupMember commands as one object. How to split them?

Tags: powershell

I have to make a script in PowerShell that shows all groups that user belongs to. What's more, if the switch `-ListAllMembers` is on, it should also show all members of these groups. The thing is that my script shows all members of different groups as one object (array) and I want them to be divided. `Get-LocalGroupMember` command is in a `foreach` loop. What can I do?

[image: Effect]

```cs
Param(
    $userToCheck,
    [switch]$listAllMembers
)

function CheckIfBelongs {
    foreach ($user in Get-LocalGroupMember $args[0]) {
        if ($user.Name -eq ($env:USERDOMAIN + "\" + $args[1])) {
            return $true
        }
    }
    return $false
}

if (!$userToCheck) {
    $userToCheck = $env:USERNAME
}

Write-Host "`nUser $userToCheck belongs to these local groups:`n"

foreach ($group in Get-LocalGroup) {
    if (CheckIfBelongs $group $userToCheck) {
        Write-Host $group.Name
        if ($listAllMembers) {
            Get-LocalGroupMember $group
        }
    }
}

exit 0
```

Comment: Just a general suggestion... You should include your code as text using the code sample editor element so it is easy to test your code and provide you an answer based on it. Image format prevent others to copy/paste it.

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Host` writes directly to the host console. Default output (as produced by `Get-LocalGroupMember`) goes to the [success output stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/). Output order is not guaranteed across streams. Also, PowerShell default formatting suppresses additional table headers when outputting objects of the same type as a table. Because of that you see only one table, and the host output before that table.

Change `Write-Host` to `Write-Output` and the output will become what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to solve the issue. I used `Out-String` to convert the object to a string and then to send it to the console. Now, it works perfectly.

Comment: You don't want to do that.